# Javascript letter selection doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays

My javascript code display letters on the top of the grid . It doesn't display on Google Chrome .The main issue is , my array `letterselection_datareturn_admindash.push(myvariable);` doesn't collect the data at all so it passes the null data to `letterselection` function so it doesn't work.  Here is the function and html code

```
function letterselection(data) {
  var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

  $.each(letters, function (key, value) {


      myNamete_admindash = 'ByLetter';
      var appends = '<li><a onclick="' + myNamete_admindash + '(\'' + value.toUpperCase() + '\')" href="#' + value.toUpperCase() + '">' + value.toUpperCase() + '</a></li>';
      $('ul.pagination').append(appends);

  });
}

var letterselection_datareturn_admindash = new Array();

function getData(myvariable, obj, i) {
  var deletedColumns = obj.length;
  $.each(deletedColumns, function (index, deletedColumn) {
    letterselection_datareturn_admindash.push(myvariable);
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If nothing else, your `_.filters` function for the `evens` variable won't work because it never returns a value (filter functions must return true or false for whether the element should be included in the filtered array).  This line `var res = key.substring(0, 3);` also perplexes me.

Comment: Also, you don't show us how either of your functions are actually called or what kind of arguments they receive.

Comment: i just updated code , that part was belonging to another thing. I just used refined code here .

Comment: The actual issue is related with  letterselection_datareturn_admindash.push(myvariable);  becasue it doesn't keep the data in the array.

Comment: How is this code intended to be invoked?    `letterselection()` appears to work fine in Chrome, but  I can't figure out what you intend to pass to `getData()`, or how the two functions are supposed to relate to one another (neither one seems to cal the other.)

Comment: letterselection(letterselection_datareturn_admindash);

Comment: All i need to fill out the array

Comment: Without a working example that behaves as desired in browsers other than chrome, all we can do is guess at what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved  . Now it is working on multiple browsers

Here is the answer  :

```
function getData(myvariable, obj, i) {
  var deletedColumns = obj.length;
 letterselection_datareturn_admindash.push(myvariable);

}
```

I refined my code by deleting this lineof the code `$.each(deletedColumns, function (index, deletedColumn) {`